# Should I place my JavaScript/ES6 functions on top before calling it?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a simple code below that populates a `<ul></ul>` with `<li>` using `fetch` api. I am using functions to populate the `<ul>`

**HTML**:

```
<ul id="people"></ul>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
const ul = document.getElementById('authors'); // Get the list
const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10'; // Get 10 random users

fetch(url)
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then((data) => {
        let people = data.results;

        return people.map(person => {
            let li = createNode('li'),
            img = createNode('img'),
            span = createNode('span');

            img.src = person.picture.medium;
            span.innerHTML = `${person.name.first} ${person.name.last}`;
            append(li, img);
            append(li, span);
            append(ul, li);
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));

function createNode(element) {
    return document.createElement(element); // Create the type of element you pass in the parameters
}

function append(parent, el) {
    return parent.appendChild(el); // Append the second parameter(element) to the first one
}
```

**Problem**: As my code grows, I will be adding functions. Should I place my functions on the bottom part of the code before invoking it?

Any idea is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why are you directly manipulating the DOM? That is just asking for issues and bugs with React. Severe react anti-pattern.

Comment: does the code above run?

Comment: That function is assigned to a variable, so it won't work like that. `getPeople` is `undefined`.

Comment: Arrow functions have to be defined to use them. Regular functions can be called before their apparent definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read about javascript hoisting. Then you will know variable declaration and functions definition are hoisted at the top.

So as you run the JS file, your function will, figuratively speaking, move to top. Or you can say will be interpret them first.

Also variable declarations are hoisted before function definition.

But function expressions are not hoisted like function declaration. The variable declaration is hoisted and then the function is assigned to the variable later on in the code.

Basically JavaScript interpreter "looks ahead" to find all the variable declarations and "hoists" them to the top of the function.

There are multiple articles on this online. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) docs to start with.

```
 helloWorld();

 function helloWold() { return "hello world"; }
```

This works because, losely speaking the interpreted version looks like

```
  function helloWorld() { ... }
  helloWorld()
```

But

```
  helloWorld();
  var helloWorld = function() {}
```

translates to

```
  var helloWorld;
  helloWorld(); // error, because helloWorld is undefined

  helloWorld = function() {}
```

Hope that clears up.

Also the same rules of hoisting applies inside a function. Because of function scope.

So imagine something like

```
  var foo = 10;
  (function() {
    console.log(foo);
    var foo = 20;
  })()
```

will translate to

```
  var foo;
  foo = 10;

  (function() {
    var foo;
    console.log(foo); // logs undefined, foo is redefined inside the function
    foo = 20;
  })()

  console.log(foo); // logs 10
```

Answer (score 1):

If you declare it as a function declaration, you can called it in any part of the script, a function declaration is:

```js
function myFunctionDeclaration() {}
```

How another users say, will be better if you use React to manipulate the DOM (if you are using this library)